# How to use placeholder when using .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, placeholder

I am trying to add a new `div` to a form which contains some input fields. Like:

```html
<form id = "def">
<input type = "text" placeholder = "abc">
</form>
<script>

var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type = text placeholder = " + "ghi gyt" + ">";
def.appendChild(newdiv);
</script>
```

But when I do this, in the output only "ghi" of placeholder is visible. And anything after first space is not visible ("gyt") in this case. How to fix this?

I am creating a new div because I need to style those input fields differently. I am using Chrome 49.

Comment: Using `"` inside `double-quoted-string` will break the string literal...Use `"<input type = 'text' placeholder ='ghi gyt'>";`

Comment: I am not using " inside string.. I am appending several strings together..

Comment: You must use quotes around attribute values in markup that contain spaces or any character other than a-z, number, dot, dash (see [*W3C HTML 5 §4.4*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes)). Also much neater to not have spaces between the attribute name, '=' and value, so consider `... "<input type='text' placeholder='" + "ghi gyt" + "'>" ...`. ;-)

Comment: @RayonDabre thanks.. It works!

Comment: Ah, seems I was too slow. Well done RobG, well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you write this to the dom it will look as follow:

```
<input type = text placeholder = ghi gyt>
```

What it should be however is:

```
<input type = text placeholder = 'ghi gyt'>
```

Since you need to encapsulate strings that contains space.

New code:

```
newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type = text placeholder = " + "'ghi gyt'" + ">";
```

It was just a simple matter of adding singlequotes, before and after your placeholder value :)

Answer (score 0):

your line

```
newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type = text placeholder = " + "ghi gyt" + ">";
```

will produce this html:

```
<input type = text placeholder = ghi gyt>
```

with no string delimiters, so `ghi` is interpreted as `placeholder` value and `gyt` as an attribute.

it's better to use string delimiters to avoid the issue:

```
newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type = 'text' placeholder ='ghi gyt' >";
```

```html
<form id = "def">
<input type = "text" placeholder = "abc">
</form>
<script>

var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type = 'text' placeholder ='ghi gyt' >";
def.appendChild(newdiv);
</script>
```

Comment: `type = text placeholder` ?

Answer (score 0):

use correct quotation...

```html
<form id = "def">
<input type = "text" placeholder = "abc avc">
</form>
<script>

var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type = text placeholder = " + "'ghi fff '"  + ">";
def.appendChild(newdiv);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate between single and double quotes and you don't need so much whitespace surrounding the `=` when writing attributes--it's just easier to read said attributes if you wrap the values in quotes (although it's still valid without them, except when the value has whitespace, like `"ghi gyt"`).

```
'<input type="text" placeholder="ghi gyt">'
```

```html
<form id="def">
<input type="text" placeholder="abc">
</form>
<script>

var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="ghi gyt">';
def.appendChild(newdiv);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```html
<form id = "def">
<input type = "text" placeholder = "abc">
</form>
<script>

var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder=" + "'ghi gyt'" + ">";
def.appendChild(newdiv);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type = text placeholder = " + "ghi gyt" + ">";
```

Into this

```
 newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type = text placeholder ='" + "ghigyt" + "' >";
```

Comment: If you read answers permitted / commented, you'll see this one already exists.

Comment: All the answers here popped up as soon as I posted :). There were 0 answers initially.

Comment: @sciencefyll This my first time posting here. And like I mentioned there were no answers when I started answering it! I don't think the downvote is fair :(

Comment: You should look out for dom updates, there will be warnings that there are new answers registered. Since you're new I wish I could remove my downvote, but it seems its too late... Anyways welcome to stackoverflow, happy solving! :)

Comment: @sciencefyll Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try like this . Its working as you expected

```html
<form id = "def">
<input type = "text" placeholder = "abc">
</form>
<script>

var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type = text placeholder = 'ghi gyi'>";
def.appendChild(newdiv);
</script>
```